# Как получить значения узлов в MS SQL в XML

Tags: xml, sql-server

Допустим в одной из колонок таблицы есть поле типа XML, которое имеет ~ такую структуру:

```xml
<root>
<row id="1">
<field>123qwe</field>
<field>123qwe</field>
</row>
<row id="2">
<field>123qwe</field>
</row>
<row id="3">
<field>123qwe</field>
<field>123qwe</field>
</row>
</root>
```

Как мне из него получить результирующий набор вида:

```
rowId   fieldValue
------- ------------
1       123qwe
1       123qwe
2       123qwe
3       123qwe
3       123qwe
```

Comment: поясните, что у вас в выходной строке приведено? и для примера лучше берите различающиеся значения строк.

Comment: ммм, как вам сказать, вложеные таблицы запрещены, вам прийдётся присоиденяит id к чему-то. Как вы видите резутьтат? Прямо так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут можно либо выбирать узлы `field`, а id выбирать через XPath к родительскому узлу, либо выбирать узлы `row`, и через них обращаться к `field` (два раза применить `nodes`).

Т.е.

```
declare @xml xml = '...';

select
    rowId = field.x.value('../@id', 'int'),
    fieldValue = field.x.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
from
    @xml.nodes('/root[1]/row/field') field(x);
```

или

```
select
    rowId = row.x.value('@id', 'int'),
    fieldValue = field.x.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
from
    @xml.nodes('/root[1]/row') row(x)
    cross apply row.x.nodes('field') field(x);
```

Применительно к таблице со столбцом xml-типа всё аналогично. Просто `@xml.nodes(...)` заменяется на `[TableName] t cross apply t.XmlColumn.nodes(...)`.

Comment: Да, двойной Nodes сработал.